# Magento2 - Reload page after remove item from Minicart

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

**I have been trying to reload the page after removing item from Minicart** in Magento2, Can anyone help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Copy `sidebar.js` file from below path

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js
```

And create a file have below path

```
app/design/frontend/{ your vendor}/{your theme}/Magento_Checkout/web/js
```

And Change line 192

```
_removeItemAfter: function (elem, response) {
        },
```

to

```
_removeItemAfter: function (elem, response) {
            window.location.reload(); 
        },
```

And After Run below Command :

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```